# BGE animation property?

Tags: animation, game-engine, properties

Is it possible to give an animation frame a property so to say?   I want to hold down a button and play the beginning or first half of my animation.  Call it frame 1-12.   A flipper animation.  IF you hold it down until frame 12 I want frame 12 to trigger the next 12 frames of the 24 frame animation.    Essentially If you dont hold the attack button long enough it wont play the full attack.  Just the wind up frames... Then revert/flipper back to the beginning.      What is a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have an answer for that- but it requires an xbox 360 gamepad. Check out this game if you have a 360 controller...
[image]